# IWshShortcut target path does not take two dots in the target file name

Tags: c#

I'm trying t create a shortcut in using the IWshShortcut and WshShell. My exe - for which I'm creating the shortcut has two dots in the file name. 
Here is what I'm doing:

```
        string link = Path.Combine(TargetPath, Path.GetFileName(FileName) ?? FileName);
            link = Path.ChangeExtension(link, string.Concat(Path.GetExtension(link), ShortcutExtensionString));

            var shell = new WshShell();
            var shortcut = shell.CreateShortcut(link) as IWshShortcut;

shortcut.Description = Description;
                    shortcut.Arguments = string.Join(" ", Parameters);
                    shortcut.TargetPath = Path.Combine(WorkingDirectory, "CompanyName.ApplicationName.exe");
                    shortcut.WorkingDirectory = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(WorkingDirectory)
                        ? TargetPath
                        : WorkingDirectory;
                    //save the shortcut.
                    shortcut.Save();
```

With this, the code gets executed well, but the target path in the desktop shortcut comes truncated for the exe name like this: "E:\OSO\App\bin\CompanyName.exe"
[image]

The whole thing happens from a laptop to create the shortcut in a remote server. I use WNetAddConnection2 to connect to the desktop directory of the server for the logged on user (providing the username and pwd for the admin user).

It appears to work fine for the local laptop though.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the target path as below,

```
shortcut.TargetPath = WorkingDirectory + @"\CompanyName.ApplicationName.exe";
```

Comment: Nope, no luck. I forgot to mention this problem comes only in case of remote creation (updated my question accordingly). Thanks for the suggestion though.